# MYSQL Select priority data if exist

Tags: mysql, sql

My current data :

```
Month      Price A Price B  Status Approval

January    1000    2000      1        0
February   1000    2000      1        0
March      1000    2000      1        0
April      1000    2000      1        0
May        1000    2000      1        0
June       1000    2000      1        0
July       1000    2000      1        0
August     1000    2000      1        0  
September  1000    2000      1        0  
October    1000    3000      1        0   
October    2000    2000      2        0
October    3000    2000      2        1
November   1000    2000      1        0
December   1000    2000      1        0

*Status 1 = Not Changed, Status 2 = Changed, Approval 1 = Approved
```

> What i'm trying to show,is
>  when month > 1 (my case is October)
>   ,
> IF `STATUS = 2 AND APPROVAL = 1` IS NOT EXIST,
> Show data with
>   STATUS = 1 AND APPROVAL = 0
> ELSE SHOW `STATUS = 2 AND APPROVAL =
>   1` Using group by, 
>  doesn't work,it shows first data if month more
>   than 1

My Query :

```
SELECT A.NAME AS MONTH, 
  IFNULL( B.PRICE_A, 0 ) PRICE_A,
  IFNULL( B.PRICE_B, 0 ) PRICE_B,
  STATUS,
  APPROVAL, 
FROM 
  REF_MONTH A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT
    SUBSTR( PERIOD, '5,2' ) MONTH,
    ROUND( PRICE_A_FIX, 2 ) PRICE_A,
    ROUND( PRICE_B_FIX, 2 ) PRICE_B,
    A.STATUS,
    A.APPROVAL,
FROM
    PRICE_MONTH_LIST A
WHERE
    SUBSTR( PERIOD, 1, 4 ) = 2018 
) B ON B.MONRH= A.MONTH
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( 2018, month), '%Y%m' ), '%Y%m' ) <= 
DATE_FORMAT( SYSDATE( ), '%Y%m' )
GROUP BY A.MONTH
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

My Expected Result :

```
Month      Price A Price B  Status Approval

January    1000    2000      1        0
February   1000    2000      1        0
March      1000    2000      1        0
April      1000    2000      1        0
May        1000    2000      1        0
June       1000    2000      1        0
July       1000    2000      1        0
August     1000    2000      1        0  
September  1000    2000      1        0  
October    3000    2000      2        1
November   1000    2000      1        0
December   1000    2000      1        0
```

Comment: What about the prices in your example? If you group by you'll lose that data, is that right?

Comment: Have considered using the [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement

Comment: the prices didn't lost @Ben

Comment: i'm trying to use Case Statement,but i always failed because i didn't know where to put the Case Statement @kellymandem

Comment: If you group by month, then you won't see the prices. If you group by month, price a and price b, then you'll get 3 rows for October, so you need to know how you should handle the price values.

Comment: Can you add expected results for the above data with explanation

Comment: i already show my current query @Ben

Comment: i already update the question with expected results @Vijiy

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query -

```
with table1 as
(
  select 'January' as month, 1000 as priceA, 2000 as priceB, 1 as status, 0 as approval from dual
  union all
  select 'October' as month, 1000 as priceA, 3000 as priceB, 1 as status, 0 as approval from dual
  union all 
  select 'October' as month, 2000 as priceA, 2000 as priceB, 2 as status, 0 as approval from dual
  union all
  select 'October' as month, 3000 as priceA, 2000 as priceB, 2 as status, 1 as approval from dual
  )
,t1 as 
(
select month, count(*) as cnt, min(status) as min_status, 
max(status) max_status, min(approval) min_app, max(approval) max_app from table1
group by month
)
,t2 as 
(
select 
month,
case when cnt>1 and max_status<>2 and max_app<>1 then min_status else max_status end as status1,
case when cnt>1 and max_status<>2 and max_app<>1 then min_app else max_app end as approval1
from t1
)
select
t.month,
t.priceA,
t.priceB,
t.status,
t.approval
from table1 t
inner join t2 on t.month=t2.month and t.status=t2.status1 and t.approval=t2.approval1;
```

result -

```
January 1000    2000    1   0
October 3000    2000    2   1
```

As there were no insert scripts, I have use CTE with oralce db.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The other month must be shown too,so it would show 12 month,october with 2 and 1

Comment: In the query which i have given, i have taken only 2 months, you have to put this snippet into your query and try. query which u gave is different from table structure month